# Apple Pay. Workflow

Tags: java, ios, e-commerce, applepay

I don't clearly understand - how Apple Pay works in case of online checkout via online store.

From my understanding:
  Prerequisites:
    1) Card which will be used for payment should be added to Passbook.
    2) During adding this card to passbook Apple device sends request with PAN to issuer and if verification is passed - format unique token, which is stored in AppleSecurity element.

When customer try to make purchase online via online store: 1) customer should switch the card, which will be used for payment  2) Store formats the request with total amount, shipping address and token, which is stored on Security element 3) Apple device sends request to AppleServer for payment authorization  4) After this store can executes additional logic (whatever)

Feel free to correct me if I'm wrong.

But my question is - if existing system already uses tokenization service, payment gateway and payment processor - how it can be integrated with Apple Pay?

Answer (score 4):

You need to look at the documentation on Apple. Your description of the way apple pay works is correct in the first part, and incorrect in the second part. There's a good [tutorial on Apple Pay](http://www.raywenderlich.com/87300/apple-pay-tutorial) at Ray Wenderlich.com that shows how to implement it.

Here's a general description:
Within an app, Apple Pay is just a source for payment details. The app is responsible for

- creating a payment request (with line items and a total)
- triggering the apple pay interface
- checking any shipping details
- contacting the back end or a service (Stripe, etc) to create a token for the specific purchase
- sending the successful purchase token to the app's server to record the purchase

So there are two tokens needed:  one for the user's payment details (the card) and a second token for the actual purchase. In loose terms, Apple Pay is responsible for generating the first one, but the app + some service is responsible for generating the second one.